# Why facebook does not make clear the number of requests in graph api?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I want to know why facebook does not make clear the number of requests we can made in the graph api.

I know that they have made available some documentation about the requests  limits to the graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting), but they speak of a "score" in the user level rate limiting, and the sum of "number of calls and queries made, cpu time spent, memory used for each app." in the app level rate limiting, while other APIs, such as instagram, twitter, google plus, has very clear boundaries, making it much simpler to control the calls we need to do for the apis.

Why they just simple put some call limits to every level of the api limits model?

And if they do so, can someone show me the way to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has very beautiful principle that it always is trying to remain as simple as possible. With the employment of limited graphics, it tries to attract maximum users. Hope you understand what I am trying to convey.

Comment: I think i understand what you say, but the simplicity of work with Instagram API, for instance, is far better in relation to request limits control.